# jQuery event won't work on dynamically fetched HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I want to change the innerHTML of all span tags when they are clicked that have the attribute 'data-change':

```
$('span[data-change]').click(function(){
 $(this).text('Text was changed dynamically');
});
```

Now, if I add a new span tag with data-change attribute inside my html document using jQuery on javascript, the onclick event won't work on the newly added span tags. Why? And how can I make them work? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried delegation?

Comment: I don't understand. What is delegation?

Comment: if it is dynamically created you might need to do it using jquery "on" or jquery "live"..

Comment: @JohanLevitt: Refer to either my answer or Arun's answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation, when registering events for dynamic elements.

You can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to register delegated events.

```
$(document).on('click', 'span[data-change]', function(){
    $(this).text('Text was changed dynamically');
});
```

You can also read [this](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events)

Comment: I didn't know about this. Thanks! Can you provide any tutorial link where I can learn more about "Delegation"?

Comment: And do your best NOT to use `$(document).on(...)` but an element that will contain your dynamic elements for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use delegation for dynamically created elements like below:

```
$(document).on('click','span[data-change]',function(){
    $(this).text('Text was changed dynamically');
});
```

The jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) API page has more details and example.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).delegate('click', 'span[data-change]', function(){
  $(this).text('Text was changed dynamically');
});
```

or

```
 $(document).on('click', 'span[data-change]', function(){
     $(this).text('Text was changed dynamically');
 });
```

More info

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
  http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events